# RightToLeft Layout in DevComponents.DotNetBar.SuperGrid

Tags: c#, dotnetbar

I want to change `RightToLeft` Layout in `DevComponents.DotNetBar.SuperGrid` to Yes or true , but when I set the property to `Yes` the layout was not changed.

Here's my code:

```
dataGridView1.RightToLeft =  System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
```

How can I correctly set the `RightToLeft` property?